# slideToggle() and Table tag with unknown height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to `slideToggle()` a `table` with no set height. Is this possible?

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p class="expand-close"><a href="">Expand/Close</a></p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Head 1</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Head 2</td>
        <td>More stuff</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("p.expand-close").parent().click(function (event) {
    $(this).parent().find("table").slideToggle(400);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And the CSS:

> table {display: none;}

There's no slide animation which I am assuming is because no height is set on the `table`? If so, is there a way to do the slide animation?

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BRuvf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideToggle` adds `display: table` property to your table, as it's not block element, you don't see the animation effect. You can put your table within a div tag and slide that instead:

```
<div id='table'>
   <table>
     // ..
   </table>
</div>
```

```
#table {
    display: none;
}
```

```
$("p.expand-close a").click(function (event) {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(400);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NrkCg/

Answer (score 0):

This solve your problem

**CSS**

```
table{
    display:block;
}
.container table{
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("p.expand-close").parent().click(function (event) {
     var block = $(this).parent().find("table");

    if(block.is(':visible'))
        $(block).slideUp(400);
    else
       $(block).slideDown(400, function(){$(this).css('display', 'block')});

    event.preventDefault();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2G2mD/